# How to get a list of all the smart contract account ids and WASM blobs on a parachain

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, substrateinterface

I would like to figure out how to get a list of all the smart contracts account ids and WASM blobs that have been uploaded to a specific parachain, ideally into python using the substrate interface.  [This picture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/241530/198211830-9b1f1731-e70d-4083-ae9a-ee5e3e5b8be2.png) shows that `contracts` is one of the options under selected chain state, but when I go to [polkadotjs](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate) I don't see the `contracts` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing with you the code about how to do it using PolkadotJS. Using python should be calling the same functions.

First connect to the parachain you want to query

```js
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944"');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
```

After get all the contracts (where you will get the account ids you are looking for) calling the extrinsic `contractInfoOf` but instead of specifying and account ID querying all the entries.

```js
  const contracts = await api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf.entries();
```

Finally go through all the contracts you got, parse the data to get the account ID and the codeHash.

You are going to use the codeHash to call the extrinsic `codeStorage` in order to get the code.

```js
    for (const contract of contracts){
      const accountId = contract[0].toHuman()[0];

      const codeHash = contract[1].toHuman().codeHash;
      const codeStorage = await api.query.contracts.codeStorage(codeHash);
      const code = codeStorage.toHuman().code;

      console.log(`Accountid: ${accountId} - Code: ${code}`);
    };
```