# Is there a way to render all values of a storage in drop down through Polkadot JS UI?

Tags: polkadot-js, storage

I have a scenario where I have to enter all values of a storage in drop down through Polkadot JS UI.

Suppose I have a pallet `TestPallet` and an extrinsic `rate`. There are two storage `Items`  and `Rating`.

If a user selects `TestPallet` >> `rate`, I want to show all the items stored in `Items` so that user can select and rate.

In `Items`, items are stored with an id. So when user selects any item, I can store in `Rating` with `ItemId`.

Can someone please help me to provide the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve a list of all the keys and entries from a maps and double-maps with: `.entries(<args>): [StorageKey, Type][]`.

An example in your case will be more or less like this:

```
const items = await api.query.testPallet.items.entries();
```

And this will be an array of key-values.

See in this previous StackExchange question an example to get all contracts: [How to get a list of all the smart contract account ids and WASM blobs on a parachain](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6534/2762)

And see an example in the [PolkadotJS docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other/).

Comment: sorry I still didn’t get my solution. How can I display list in Polkadot Js UI on extrinsic page?

Comment: Ahh sorry, In the current PolkadotJS UI this is not possible, but you can implement that if you have a custom UI using the polkadot-js library